# Lobatto quadrature rule

Tags: integration, reference-request, numerical-methods

Where can one find explanation and rigorous 
theoretical introduction to Gauss-Lobatto,
Gauss-Radau, Gauss-Kronrod rules. Also
pros and cons of each method are of interest too.

Answer (score 0):

[Methods of Numerical Integration by Davis and Rabinowitz](https://www.elsevier.com/books/methods-of-numerical-integration/davis/978-0-12-206360-2) gives a thorough introduction to the topic, especially Chapter 2.
For a review of error estimates, you might find [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.4629.pdf) helpful.

For the individual methods, you could consider the linked papers:
[Gauss-Lobatto](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2000-69-229/S0025-5718-99-01078-9/S0025-5718-99-01078-9.pdf), [Gauss-Radau](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44237388), and [Gauss-Kronrod](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1997-66-219/S0025-5718-97-00861-2/S0025-5718-97-00861-2.pdf)